# How to sort values based on selection in an Altair chart?

Tags: altair

Given an interactive area chart like this:

```py
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.iowa_electricity()
selection = alt.selection(type='multi', fields=['source'], bind='legend')

alt.Chart(source).mark_area().encode(
    x="year:T",
    y="net_generation:Q",
    color="source:N",
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.1))
).add_selection(selection)
```

I would like to sort the selected values first so they stack up from the bottom and don't "hang in thin air" like in the example below:

[image]

However, I can't see how I would express this in a transformation. The only thing that works is `transform_filter(selection)` but that completely removes the values that are not selected.

Is this not possible or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can do this is to access the contents of the selection within a [calculate transform](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/transform/calculate.html), using a [vega expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) to find whether the current column is in the selection. At this point, you can set the order to this encoding:

```python
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

source = data.iowa_electricity()
selection = alt.selection(type='multi', fields=['source'], bind='legend')

alt.Chart(source).add_selection(
    selection
).transform_calculate(
    order=f"indexof({selection.name}.source || [], datum.source)",
).mark_area().encode(
    x="year:T",
    y="net_generation:Q",
    color="source:N",
    opacity=alt.condition(selection, alt.value(1), alt.value(0.1)),
    order=alt.Order("order:N", sort='descending'),
).add_selection(selection)
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the great answer! Anywhere the elements of this neat trick are documented, especially the part that `selection` has a `name` property? I suppose it returns e.g. `["Fossil Fuels", "Renewables"]`, so then the interpolated expression in Javascript is `["Fossil Fuels", "Renewables"].source`. And here I'm drawing a blank and don't understand anymore... 

Comment: There's an example of using selection values in expressions here: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#selection-values-in-expressions The selection object is referenced by the name within vega expressions, and it has an attribute for each field that returns a list of selected values for that field.